# Multipart Comment in HTML

Tags: html

How do I add two fields to one comment? (Below I have the radio option & the Text option)

I am creating a comment box for tracking messages and how they were contacted.
I have below. This works for the comment in DIVI THEMES. It will only post the radio or the comment.

I am new and self taught so I am sure its not perfect.

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

```
<div id="respond" class="comment-respond">
  <h6 id="reply-title" class="comment-reply-title"><span>
          Contact Type</span> <small><a rel="nofollow" id="cancel-comment-reply-link" href="/?page_id=12139#respond" style="display:none;">Cancel reply</a></small></h6>
  <form action="https://m13a01s19t20e05r18c03h08a01r18t20.com/wp-comments-post.php" method="post"
    id="commentform" class="comment-form">
    <tr>
      <input type="Radio" id="phone" name="comment" value="Phone - " "other_reason"><label for="Phone">Phone <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="btn-group-id"> <input type="text" name="other_reason" placeholder="Message"/>
    </label><br>
      <input type="Radio" id="text" name="comment" value="Text"><label for="Text">Text</label><br>
      <input type="Radio" id="email" name="comment" value="Email"><label for="Email">E-Mail</label><br></tr>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="comment2"><br>
    </p>
    <p class="form-submit"><button name="submit" type="submit" id="et_pb_submit" class="submit et_pb_button">Confirm</button> <input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="12139" id="comment_post_ID">
      <input type="hidden" name="comment_parent" id="comment_parent" value="0">
    </p><input type="hidden" id="_wp_unfiltered_html_comment_disabled" name="_wp_unfiltered_html_comment" value="edb001f0fd">

    <script>
      (function() {
        if (window === window.parent) {
          document.getElementById('_wp_unfiltered_html_comment_disabled').name = '_wp_unfiltered_html_comment';
        }
      })();
    </script>
  </form>
</div>
<!-- #respond -->
</section>

</div>
</div>
```

<!-- end snippet -->

Comment: You are inconsistent with your usage of a closing slash on the `<input>` tag but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.